# Android Mediaplayer strange TimeoutException exception

Tags: android, timeoutexception

I'm dealing with an strange crash reported by the app coming from the MediaPlayer. It seems that the system tries to finalize the MediaPlayer and it returns a TimeOut exception.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.media.MediaPlayer.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
       at android.media.MediaPlayer.native_finalize(MediaPlayer.java)
       at android.media.MediaPlayer.finalize(MediaPlayer.java:2391)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I'm looking for it around internet and other forums but I can't get any reason/explanation to that crash. Is there anyone suffering it too or that might help with it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I didn't @SyedaZunairah, I ended up using ExoPlayer which I recommend you to use https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer